# Can I use "as" as a variable in Laravel Eloquent or MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

What I have in my application are the following two queries:

```
SUM(cost_of_sales + commissions) as sales_costs
```

```
SUM((cost_of_sales + commissions) * tax) as sales_costs
```

What I want is to use sales_costs as a variable from the first query into the second one. 
What I want to achieve looks something like the following:

```
SUM(cost_of_sales + commissions) as sales_costs
```

```
SUM(sales_cots * tax)
```

How can I achieve this in Laravel Eloquent?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this would be to use the raw functionality.
See [Raw Expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#raw-expressions)